# How do I access an attribute from a counted resource within another resource?

Tags: terraform

I'm using Terraform to script an AWS build.  I'm spinning up a number of instances across multiple availability zones, in this example, 2:

```
resource "aws_instance" "myinstance" {
    count                   = 2
    ami                     = "${var.myamiid}"
    instance_type           = "${var.instancetype}"
    availability_zone       = "${data.aws_availability_zones.all.names[count.index]}"
    # other details omitted for brevity
}
```

I now need to assign an Elastic IP to these instances, so that I can rebuild the instances in the future without their IP address changing.  The below shows what I'd *like* to do:

```
resource "aws_eip" "elastic_ips" {
    count    = 2
    instance = "${aws_instance.myinstance[count.index].id}"
    vpc      = true
}
```

But this errors with:

> expected "}" but found "."

I've also tried using `lookup`:

```
instance = "${lookup(aws_instance.sbc, count.index).id}"
```

but that fails with the same error.

How can I go about attaching Elastic IPs to these instances?

Answer (score 15):

Please go through [terraform interpolation - element list index](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#element-list-index-)

> element(list, index) - Returns a single element from a list at the given index. If the index is greater than the number of elements, this function will wrap using a standard mod algorithm. This function only works on flat lists. Examples:

```
element(aws_subnet.foo.*.id, count.index)
```

So in your case, the code will be:

```
instance = "${element(aws_instance.myinstance.*.id, count.index}"
```

Comment: So this has the added benefit of wrapping around - are there any other reasons to use it that I'm not seeing?  Will definitely keep it in mind for the future, but I think in my case I'd rather get an error than wrap around, since it's supposed to be a 1-1 mapping between the two resources.

Comment: I used your way before, but looks hashicorp updated their documents with the new way. Both ways should work.

Answer (score 8):

A bit more playing around and I've found the answer - you can index into the "splat" syntax:

```
instance = "${aws_instance.myinstance.*.id[count.index]}"
```

Comment: Even better, just go: `instance = aws_instance.myinstance.*.id[count.index]`

Answer (score 3):

This works for me,

```
instance = aws_instance.myinstance.*.id
```

Answer (score 2):

try using `aws_instance.jserver[count.index].id`

e.g. of ec2 instance and volume attachment is

```
  resource "aws_instance" "jserver"{
    count=3
  }
  
  resource "aws_volume_attachment" "j_ebs_att" {
    count = 3
    ...
    instance_id = aws_instance.jserver[count.index].id
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers already pointed out that counted elements must be accessed via indexes. I like to add that I encountered the error

```
Because aws_instance.some-resource has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
```

although I had already fixed that particular line. The error kept showing up, mentioning a line with some code segment that was not even present any longer in my code.

I was able to resolve this by fixing all places where I had not accessed a specific instance (which were also mentioned in other errors). In my case, an output section was not adapted previously. Only then all errors disappeared all of a sudden.

Answer (score 1):

I know you are using older version of terraform but I still want to add just in case someone is struggling with the same issue with terraform 0.12. For terraform version 11 the syntax is totally different from version v12. As you can see it's only the interpolation that should be removed. From your syntax and the various response provided.

```
version 11:
instance = "${aws_instance.myinstance.*.id[count.index]}"

version 12
instance = aws_instance.myinstance.*.id[count.index]
```