# How do I access the NAT IP of a counted google_compute_instance in a connection block?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to create multiple instances with `count = number`. During this I need to access IP address of created instance but I can't access attribute in loop. My version of Terraform is 0.12.26.

I've tried several approaches and nothing. Everything works until I try to access number of created instance via `count.index`. This is the code:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "test" {
  count        = 2
  name         = "test-${count.index}"
  
  # irrelevant stuff

  connection {
    host        = google_compute_instance.test.*.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip[count.index]
    
    # irrelevant stuff
```

I also tried advises from here with no luck:
[How do I access an attribute from a counted resource within another resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679456/how-do-i-access-an-attribute-from-a-counted-resource-within-another-resource#44686835)

According to those posts I've tried:

```
host = google_compute_instance.test[count.index].network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip
host = element(google_compute_instance.test.*.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip, count.index)
```

Every time I get:

```
Error: Cycle: google_compute_instance.test[1], google_compute_instance.test[0]
```

How do I access the NAT IP of a counted google_compute_instance in a connection block?

Comment: A resource can't refer to itself during creation like this.

Comment: When I use `google_compute_instance.test.0.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip` it works perfectly (for one instance).

Comment: Curious. That's good to know. It might be because the connection block is for post-creation remote-exec provisioners. I was not expecting that to work.

Comment: Have you any idea how to walk around this? I need access IP address of each instance to copy files to it via ssh.

Comment: Please give my answer a try. I think it should work.

Comment: Also consider **metadata_startup_script**. It runs on instance start and you could download from Google Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have an example of self-reference working for a single resource, this should work for the counted resources:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "test" {
  count        = 2
  name         = "test-${count.index}"
  
  # irrelevant stuff

  connection {
    host        = self.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip
    
   # irrelevant stuff
```

> ### The `self` Object
>
> Expressions in `connection` blocks cannot refer to their parent resource by name. Instead, they can use the special `self` object.
>
> The `self` object represents the connection's parent resource, and has all of that resource's attributes. For example, use `self.public_ip` to reference an `aws_instance`'s `public_ip` attribute.

[The self Object from the Provisioner Connection Settings docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/connection.html#the-self-object).

Comment: I removed last `.0` from the end (probably your typo because `nat_ip` does not have any attributes). It gives me `Error: Cycle: google_compute_instance.test[1], google_compute_instance.test[0]` as well.

Comment: Interesting. I'm very surprised that the single instance case worked.

Comment: It worked and copied files like a charm to single instance with no error :) btw `(google_compute_instance.test[0]).network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip` works as well.

Comment: Great! Yes. I got confused when I was transcribing the answer. I've corrected it with your guidance. Thank you!

Comment: But it probably still fails in the multiple instance case I'm guessing. I'm thinking there's something odd about connection on counted resource. I'll do some reading.

Comment: Yes, once I want create more instances and use any of previous references with `count.index` it fails with `Error: Cycle: ...`. I really appreciate you help.

Comment: I think I've got it now! The **self** object!

Comment: That works like a charm! Thank you! I'm a bit disappointed with Terraform's misleading error message.